# How to add OnClickListener on ViewHolder 's TextView of RecyclerView.Adapter to execute AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

Firstly I have seen many solutions here but  unable to understand it.
 I am confused about how i can execute AsyncTask inside OnTextClick().
and want to know how we can implement this.
    please do help.

DownloadFormActivity.

```
public class DownloadFormActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    private String[] link_1;
    private Bitmap[] company_logo;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_form);

        Bitmap bitmap_1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.***********);
        Bitmap bitmap_2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.***********);
        Bitmap bitmap_3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.***********);

        link_1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_claimForm);
        company_logo = new Bitmap[]{bitmap_1, bitmap_2, bitmap_3};

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        FormListAdapter adapter = new FormListAdapter(this, getdata());

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        //FormListAdapter fla =new FormListAdapter(context,getdata())
    }

    private List<FormList> getdata() {
        List<FormList> listdata = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < link_1.length; i++) {
            FormList formdata = new FormList();
            formdata.setCompany_logo(company_logo[i]);
            formdata.setLink_1(link_1[i]);
            listdata.add(formdata);
        }
        return listdata;
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {

        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading File");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            int count = urls.length;
            if(count == 1) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();

                    if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                                + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
                    }

                    int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                    input = connection.getInputStream();
                    output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/file_name.extension");

                    byte data[] = new byte[4096];
                    long total = 0;
                    int datacount;
                    while ((datacount = input.read(data)) != -1) {

                        if (isCancelled()) {
                            input.close();
                            return null;
                        }
                        total += datacount;

                        if (fileLength > 0)
                            publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return e.toString();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (output != null)
                            output.close();
                        if (input != null)
                            input.close();
                    } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    }

                    if (connection != null)
                        connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            if (result != null)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Download error: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(context, "File downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

FormListAdapter

```
ublic class FormListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FormListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    List<FormList> data = Collections.emptyList();
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public FormListAdapter(Context context,List<FormList> data)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.download_form_list, parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view, new MyViewHolder.ViewHolderClicks() {
            @Override
            public void onTextClick()
            {

                    //  how to call AsyncTask here

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FormList current = data.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(current.getCompany_logo());
        holder.textView_1.setText(current.getLink_1());
        holder.textView_2.setText(current.getLink_2());
        holder.textView_3.setText(current.getLink_3());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView textView_1,textView_2,textView_3;
        private Context context;

        public ViewHolderClicks mClickListener;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView, final ViewHolderClicks mListener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.mClickListener = mListener;
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_companyLogo);
            textView_1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_link_1);
            textView_2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_link_2);
            textView_3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_link_3);
            textView_1.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            context = v.getContext();
            mClickListener.onTextClick();
        }

        public interface ViewHolderClicks
        {
            void onTextClick();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem you are getting?

Comment: when i am trying to make object of DownloadTask inside onTextClick unable to give the context

Comment: you can use getActivity() as a context

Comment: you want to click textview in your adapter class??

Comment: You are already keeping the context as a member variable then what is the issue ? Just pass this.context there

Comment: @saeed getActivity() is not available  as context

Comment: @Amarbir  yes .i  have assigned onClick  there only.

Comment: @Midhun MP : can u please post what you saying.

Answer (score 0):

Code the `AsyncTask` in its own `.java` file, and then use it in your `TextClick()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to implement `onTextClick()` on your `DownloadFormActivity`. Here is how to do it:

**FormListAdapter**

```
public class FormListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FormListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    List<FormList> data = Collections.emptyList();
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private static ClickListener mClickListener;

    public FormListAdapter(Context context,List<FormList> data)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.download_form_list, parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FormList current = data.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(current.getCompany_logo());
        holder.textView_1.setText(current.getLink_1());
        holder.textView_2.setText(current.getLink_2());
        holder.textView_3.setText(current.getLink_3());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        mClickListener = clickListener;
    }


    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView textView_1,textView_2,textView_3;
        private Context context;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_companyLogo);
            textView_1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_link_1);
            textView_2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_link_2);
            textView_3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_link_3);
            textView_1.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `DownloadFormActivity` implement `ForumListAdapter.ClickListener`. To use the listener:

```
FormListAdapter adapter = new FormListAdapter(this, getdata());
mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

and then you just have to use the interface:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
    new DownloadTask().execute(YOUR_DATA);
}
```

This is how I implemented this in my application.

The `onItemClick` will work for any Item, or you just can rename it to `onTextClick()`.